# Azure GRANT ALTER ANY EVENT SESSION

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure

What is the correct way to give someone permission to create extended event sessions in Azure SQL Server?

I've been bouncing queries to my manager non-stop today, because when he tried to grant me permission to do it myself using the following statement:

```
GRANT ALTER ANY EVENT SESSION TO myUserName
```

He got the following errors:
`Securable class 'server' not supported in this version of SQL Server.` and
`This property is not supported: ApplicationName.`

Has anyone else ever needed to grant this permission before on an azure sql database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the documentation ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-xevent-db-diff-from-svr#permission-model)) one must have Control permission on the database to issue a CREATE EVENT SESSION and the same permission should be required for the ALTER EVENT SESSION.